# Is the Figure-Ground Theory adaptable for inversion in subjunctive condition clauses in English?

Tags: english, subjunctive

People use Figure-Ground Theory to explain inversions. By putting ground before figure, emphasis focus changes.

But how to explain inversion in condition clauses for subjunctive mood?

In English, if clauses containing past subjunctive 'were', as well as some other constructions that are used similarly to subjunctives, can be recast using inversion of subject and verb, with the conjunction 'if' being dropped.

Can Figure-Ground Theory explain this?

If not, what theories can be used to explain this kind of inversions for subjunctive mood?

Comment: AFAIK many Germanic languages support conditional subclauses without 'if' and with inversion, and some not only in the subjunctive. But I'm suspecting it's not an etymological answer you're looking for?

Comment: Can you explain this theory a bit more?

Comment: @Cerberus One sentence for Figure-Ground Theory: When we see a cup on the table, we notice the figure (cup) out of the ground (table). Inversions in languages is similar to putting ground before figure.

Comment: @weakish: Yeah I read part of the Wiki article, but I still don't understand how or why inversion could correspond to putting ground "before" figure. Inversion serves to convey meaning/information by being in contrast with normal word order, if that's what you mean?

Comment: @dainichi Very helpful for me. Can you point me to some materials/articles to read more about inversions in conditional subclauses in Germanic languages?

Comment: @Cerberus Well, I guess if we say 'On the table is a cup of tea', we put the ground(table) before figure(cup). But to be honest, I suspect this too. ;-) Thus I want to find out if Figure-Ground Theory is suitable for some particular types of inversions (like inversions in subjunctive conditional clauses). If not, then the using of Figure-Ground to explain inversion is more suspectable.

Comment: @weakish: So what makes the table the ground, and the cup the figure? Their physical properties? Or does this have to do with *topic* v. *focus*? As to the other Germanic languages, German and Dutch have similar conditional inversion: *had ik hem gezien, dan...* (Dutch: "had I him seen, then...", where "I had" is the normal order). I believe German can do exactly the same thing. I think French too has a somewhat similar kind of conditional inversion, as in *avait-il une femme, Jean la garderait bien* ("had-he a woman, John would guard her well"), but I'm not 100 % sure how this works exactly.

Comment: @weakish, I haven't been able to find any backup of my claim about "not only in the subjunctive" except for Danish, where e.g. "Kommer han, så kommer han" (lit. "comes he, then comes he" -> "If he comes, he comes") is valid although this is not subjunctive or irrealis. Not sure about other Germanic languages, though. Please note that the inversion in the main clause is a V2 feature, so not related to the question.

Comment: @Cerberus Maybe because most of the time table is less useful than things on the table? So human beings evolves to notice things on the table first? Yes, German can do the same thing. *Wäre ich vorgestern nach Berlin gekommen* = *Wenn ich vorgestern nach Berlin gekommen wäre* ('if I came to Berlin the day before yesterday')

Comment: @weakish: Hmm I'm afraid all this still sounds a bit vague to me.

Comment: @dainichi: In (modern) Dutch, no subjunctive is required. That may be because the present subjunctive has all but died: *heb ik haar eindelijk aangesproken, blijkt ze een trouwring om te hebben* ("have I her finally approached, turns out she to wear a wedding ring"). So both the protasis and the apodosis are inverted. // By the way, in Dutch, inversion also happens whenever the subject is not the first constituent of a main clause, as in: *morgen ga ik weg* ("tomorrow go I away"), instead of the normal order *ik ga* ("I go"). Perhaps this is related? Perhaps also in the other languages?

Comment: @Cerberus, the word order where the inflected verb is the second constituent is called V2 word order, and is the case in most Germanic languages. I don't know if it's in any way related to verb fronting in conditional subclauses.

Comment: @dainichi: Right, of course German has it too, but English does not.